# Differentiating UITableViewCells Using Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data, uitableview, many-to-many

I have two entities, Note and Tag, that have a many-to-many relationship.
I want to be able to tap on a Note and have a UITableView that is populated with all the Tags that exist, and all the Tags that have a relationship with the Note that was tapped have a UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark on the right.

What I've tried doing is fetching two arrays, the array with all the tags and the array with the related tags. Then I did something like this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < [self.tagArray count]; i++) {
    Tag *new = [self.tagArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([self.all containsObject: new])
    {
        new.isIn = TRUE;
    }
    else {
        new.isIn = FALSE;
    }

}
```

isIn is a property of Tag, initialized like this:

In Tag.h:

```
@property BOOL isIn;
```

In Tag.m:

```
@synthesize isIn;
```

I have a feeling this is the wrong approach though. Can anyone think of a better solution?

Comment: Are these entities stored in Core Data? or generated in memory somehow. If they are stored in Core Data, shouldn't the `isIn` property be populated for you?

Comment: Also are you displaying all of the tags no matter what? If you are.. you don't need to precheck for this info. I will post an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, if you are displaying all of the tags anyway, you don't need to precheck to see if the tag should have a checkmark or not.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    // not going to go into basic cell generation logic here
    Tag *currentTag = [self.tagArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if([self.all containsObject: currentTag])
    {
       // checkmark
    }
    else
    {
       // no checkmark
    }
    return cell;
}
```